# Помогите мне правильно внедрить php код в js функцию

Tags: javascript, seo

В уроке [PracticU - онлайн IT курсы (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWIw6lVZv7E&list=PLrXcA7Ca3B80qFbA9DxC4iq40cdrBZelo&index=1) Была реализована функция, которая заменяла текст в элементе. Я составил свой набросок функции `js`. Мне нужно что-бы функция в `js` внедряла в `div` блок код на `php` (подобие асинхронного перехода)

```js
function goTo (e) {
document.getElementById("currentPage").innerHTML = "";
for (i = e; i <= 2; i++) {
  if (i == 1) {
document.getElementById("currentPage").innerHTML += "<?php include('startpage.php')?>";
return false;
  } if (i == 2) {
document.getElementById("currentPage").innerHTML += "<?php include('endpage.php')?>";
return false;   
     } 
                         }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="goTo (1);"></input>
<input type="button" value="Register" onclick="goTo (2);"></input>
<br />
<div id="currentPage"><?include('startpage.php')?></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вам ничего не даст. PHP код выполняется при рендере страницы на сервере. Т.е. это сервер обрабатывает php код, и передаёт в браузер готовый html. Если вы хотите менять контент без перезагрузки (менять или добавлять) вам нужен аякс

вот пример, простой вставки

```js
function goTo (i) {
  var currentPage = document.getElementById("currentPage");
  if (i == 1) {
    currentPage.innerHTML = currentPage.innerHTML +  "1";

  } if (i == 2) {
      currentPage.innerHTML = "2";
 
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="goTo (1);"></input>
<input type="button" value="Register" onclick="goTo (2);"></input>
<br />
<div id="currentPage">фывфыв</div>
```

вносите элемент в переменную currentPage, что бы не обращаться к DOM лишний раз.

в f (i == 1)  - показан пример, если хотите ДОБАВИТЬ к содержимому новое (вы берёте старое содержимое, добавляете новое, и потом вся обратно кидаете в элемент)

в if (i == 2) - вы просто заменяете всё содержимое

Comment: А напиши тогда как надо  правильно вставлять, это мой первый урок по js

Comment: исправил. Но вы лучше просто смотрите дальше уроки, и практикуйте то что узнали...

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть, за что вы так ненавидите ТСа? Крайне не рекомендую смотреть эти уроки ....поток сознания от внеочередного фуллстека ...

Comment: смотрите sorax, ITVDN, loftblog, если не ошибаюсь у Гоша Дударь не плохие - это на ютуб
http://learn.javascript.ru/ - это очень здоровский ресурс для js